# titlesec: \sectionmark breaking \ifthesection?

Tags: sectioning, header-footer, titlesec

In the `titlesec` package, one may use the `\ifthesection` (or `\ifthechapter`,...) command to apply some customization commands only when a `\section` has been defined. However, it seems that using `\sectionmark` (for instance to define a short running title) breaks this feature. Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[pagestyles,outermarks]{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newpagestyle{main}{ 
\headrule
\sethead[\normalsize \thepage][][\scshape \chaptertitlename~\thechapter. \chaptertitle]
{\ifthesection{\thesection.~\sectiontitle}{}}{}{\normalsize \thepage}
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\pagestyle{main}

\chapter{First Chapter}
\lipsum
\lipsum

\chapter{Second Chapter}

\section{First Section}
\lipsum
\lipsum

\section{Second Section with a very long title that I do not want to show in the running heads but which is fine for the table of contents}
\sectionmark{Second Section}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

In this example, the odd-side headers for chapter 1 (a chapter with no sections) only shows the page number, as expected (in particular the `\ifthesection` command prevents the dot from showing up):

[image]

In chapter 2, we have a first section for which everything works fine:

[image]

But things get more complicated when it comes to the second section, which has a very long name. Let us imagine that we want the full name in the table of contents, and a short running head in the headers. The command `\sectionmark{Second Section}` normally works, but it does not when `\ifthesection` is used in the headers style definition. In the present form, we get:

[image]

I can think of three possibilities to solve this problem:

- One solution would be to remove the `\ifthesection` command in the headers style definition, but then a dot would appear in the headers for chapters with no sections. Then another way to test if this dot (or any other character) should be printed would be needed.
- Using the optional argument for the `\section` command: `\section[Second Section]{Second Section with a very long title that I do not want to show in the running heads but which is fine for the table of contents}`. Then a hack would be needed to modify the table of contents so that the full name appears.
- Playing around with marks to replace the `\sectionmark{Second Section}` with an appropriate command which does not break the `\ifthesection` command.

It seems to me that it would be preferable to choose the third solution, the other two looking more like work-arounds. However, I do not know much about the marks system. Does anybody know how to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is wanted: an explicit `\sectionmark` command makes `\ifthesection` false. You can trick `titlesec` into ignoring this setting by defining a macro similar to `\sectionmark` that doesn't perform that setting:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\sectionmarkhead}[1]{%
  \gdef\sectiontitle{#1}%
  \let\ttl@marks\ttl@tm@section
  \ttl@markboth {section}}
\makeatother
```

If you use `\sectionmarkhead{Second section}` you'll get the desired result.

Comment: It works indeed. Is there a reason why it is preferable that `\sectionmark` sets `\ifthesection` to false by default?

Comment: @Corentin I really don't know why `titlesec` does that way: the main usage of explicit `\sectionmark` commands is exactly for setting a different header without affecting the table of contents entry.

Comment: @egreg. Actually, `\sectionmark` doesn't set a different header, but rather emits another mark. If you want the botmark, that's fine, but if you want the firstmark, it does nothing (or ever worse, you'll have two different headers) because that in `\section` takes precedence (in the current page). `\sectionmark` it's intented for "numberless" sections, not for numbered ones.

Comment: @egreg I can't make your macro work with `\section*`command: if I use the pagestyle `main` defined in the OP MWE along with your macro and then write a document like `\begin{document}
\chapter{First Chapter}\lipsum[1-10]\section*{First Section with a very long title}\sectionmarkhead{First Section}\lipsum[1]\end{document}` I get a blank header instead of the desired result. Is there a workaround? Thanks in advance

Comment: @petobens Why do you think it should work with `\section*`?

Comment: @egreg It shouldn't. I would like it to work with `\section*` but I don't how to write something similar (or completely different) to perform the same task as your macro.

Comment: Do you have both numbered and unnumbered sections? In any case, probably a follow-up question is better; you can type a more complete example of what doesn't work and explain your motivations more clearly.

Comment: I'll write a follow-up question. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

If you always want the full name in the TOC (which is solution 2), use the package option `toctitles`.